# CXF service disable chunking in server response

Tags: java, .net, web-services, cxf

I am replacing a .NET web service with a Java CXF web service using SOAP and JAXWS.  The Client is fixed, and believe it or not, black-boxed.  I am trying to get the service to work identically using the Java Service and the original .NET client.  I have tried many approaches and confirmed that the response to the client is identical (bytes) to the .NET service.  I have tried returning the Windows response from the Java service to no avail which means I have an issue related to the transmission, possibly encoding.  I noticed that the response transfer-encoding=[chunked] - which I suspect may be an issue. I have not found a way to change this on the server...but since I cant modify the client, I need a work around.  I am not familiar with the .NET API but here is the message I get:

BTW - the Error from the client is `[6] ERROR - [sweeper].[SweeperService.CollectSettingsInformation] <11501> (9990) There is an error in XML document (1, 2).            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
                   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
                   at client.ReadMessageEnvelope(String xml)
                   at client.Translate(String xml)
                   at client.CollectSettingsInformation()`

**ANY** Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338504/how-to-disable-chunking-in-cxf-webservice-on-server-side

Comment: its true - seems to duplicate - was Hoping @Alex might post his proposed solution...but I get the gist - not high priority for us, just an annoying piece of work I want off the list!!!  I tried to comment that issue to revive it, but my response was deleted from view

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from several other similar solutions:

```
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    boolean isOutbound = false;
    isOutbound = message == message.getExchange().getOutMessage() || message == message.getExchange().getOutFaultMessage();

    if (isOutbound) {
        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        CachedOutputStream cs = new CachedOutputStream();
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cs);
        message.getInterceptorChain().doIntercept(message);

        try {
            cs.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(cs);

            CachedOutputStream csnew = (CachedOutputStream) message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
            String currentEnvelopeMessage = IOUtils.toString(csnew.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            csnew.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(csnew);

            int bytes = Math.toIntExact(currentEnvelopeMessage.getBytes().length);

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_RESPONSE);
            if(null != response){
                log.debug("Setting Content Length: " + bytes);
                response.setContentLength(bytes);
            }

            InputStream replaceInStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(currentEnvelopeMessage, "UTF-8");
            os.flush();

            if (os instanceof CopyingOutputStream)
                ((CopyingOutputStream)os).copyFrom( replaceInStream );
            else
                IOUtils.copy(replaceInStream, os);

            replaceInStream.close();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(replaceInStream);
            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, os);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.warn("Unable to perform change.", ioe);
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    } 
}
```